# Microsoft Edge 12: Page gets refreshed without any action

Tags: javascript, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have experienced a strange behaviour of microsoft edge 12 .
It refreshes the entire web page whenever an onchange event gets fired.
This happened within my application .Tried a lot to debug and then found it is a bug with Edge 12.

So if u have a drop down with  tags and if onchange event is configured, as soon as the user select an option from the drop down, the onchange event gets triggered and then the parent page itself gets refreshed.

Please let me know what is the reason for this.

Easily reproducible on : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange.

Just try the above link on Edge 12 or you can use browserstack incase if you dont have any local copy of the Edge 12.

Please Note: Works fine without any issue on Edge 13.

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft Edge hasn't been on version 12 for a long time now; are you still finding users of build 10240 visiting your domain(s)? As you suggested, this issue doesn't appear in Edge 13 or 14―do you need a solution for 12?

Comment: @Sampson: Thanks for the feedback  . We actually have users who might use Edge 12. So just was excited to know what can be the solution to this. And how come such a thing was missed by microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft Edge is an evergreen browser, which updates regularly, and routinely. It's unlikely we will make any changes to the instance installed for users of version 12, since there has been an update since late last year. That being said, I will try to stand up an instance of 12 and see if I can reproduce this issue. If I'm able to, I'll also investigate a work-around. Can you record a GIF of the issue? ScreenToGIF works well for this.

Comment: @Sampson: Thanks So much..Created this fiddle..
https://jsfiddle.net/j4qe1jr0/7/

As I dont have local copy of Edge 12 , I ran this fiddle on browserstack with Windows 10 and Edge 12..And the same behavior is observed. As soon as I select a drop down, the entire page refreshes..

Answer (score 0):

I just had a refresh issue today with edge 14.  I deleted all my breakpoints,  my watch items and closed all my tabs then reopened Edge and everything worked fine after that. 
But sometimes all you can do is [reset edge when things are broken](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-to-reset-microsoft-edge-windows-10).